# get checkbox click inside updatepanel by jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an update panel with a runat server div inside,
this div isn't shown in the first load of the page. I used to show it after user input the search key then reload the update panel which contain the div and fill div controls then show it.

I have a CheckBox inside this div tag and I need to get the click event of this check box with jquery

I try to use direct .click or .live but all doesn't work !!

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: post an example on jsfiddle.net or at least post your code

Comment: I use this way and it works

    // Set a deleget for updatepanel load
    $("#MyUpdatePanelID").ready(function () { 
                if (Sys)
                    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoadedHandler);
           });

    // Method which will be called when updatepanel loaded
        function PageLoadedHandler(sender, args) {
                    if (sender._postBackSettings) {
                        $("input:checkbox").click(function () { alert('Any code'); });
                    }
                }

I'm not sure if it's the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    //This will add one function to be called on every request of the update panel
     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    });

    function EndRequestHandler()
    {
    $('#checkboxID').change(function(){
    //Your functionality
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce javascript into the page to simulate the click event again. Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock or Page.RegisterStartUpScript should do it.

or 
place this inside the updatepanel

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  Sys.Application.add_load(your jquery function);
 </script>
```